# Demand supply matrix

Tags: excel, countif

I have car models arranged vertically in column A.

Now I have 2 different excel sheets of demand and supply models respectively.

If the model in the main sheet matches the model in the both demand and supply sheet,I want a "yes".

How can achive this?

Comment: Look toward adding two [COUNTIF functions](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to see if you get *2*.

Comment: Can you write the full formula for this case?

Comment: TBH Ankit Vij, if you cannot click on the link and build a formula by reading the article written and published by industry experts there really is nothing that I can do to help you.

Comment: try what @Jeeped told you, don't ask or the full formula in your case, even more if whe don't have "the code" of the excel. I mean, we don't have the sheets, whe dont have your data...

Comment: I think u haven't understood my question. I just want a "yes" against the model in the main sheet if its available in the other 2 sheets irrespective of their numbers

Comment: Then probably you don't do the correct question. Try to edit, your post, add some image about how the sheets are implemented,... add more information. Even more.. try to read the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour to know how to to better questions and don't get DV. P.D: If you can't add some image, post it in comments (with a link, or similar), asking for someone to edit your post,

Answer (score 0):

**=IF(AND((MATCH(A3,Supply!A:A,0)),MATCH(A3,Demand!A:A,0)),"Yes","No")**

You have to explain what you have tried before posting anything.